# How to resolve sub-fields such that they add optional parameters to HTTP query?

Tags: elixir, graphql, absinthe

Note: this is a greatly simplified example but the problem is the same.

I am trying to wrap an existing HTTP service, `/blog-posts`, with a GraphQL interface. The service returns some extra data in its response only if I pass in a query parameter, `extra-data=true`. So,

- `GET /blog-posts`: gets ID and title
- `GET /blog-posts?extra-data=true`: gets ID, title, and `extra-data` field

I have an Absinthe schema similar to the following:

```
query do
  field :blog_posts, non_null(list_of(non_null(:blog_post)))
  resolve &MyAppWeb.Resolvers.Blog.posts/3
end

object :blog_post do
  field :id, non_null(:id)
  field :title, non_null(:string)
  field :extra_data, :string,
    resolve: &MyAppWeb.Resolvers.Blog.post_extra_data/3
end
```

My problem is I don't know how to implement the `extra_data` resolver such that it doesn't make a redundant call to `/blog-posts?extra-data=true` after already having called `/blog-posts`. There is a middleware https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe/Absinthe.Middleware.Batch.html that is designed to help with a similar problem, N+1 queries, but I don't see how to apply it in my case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

### One Optional Field

If it's just one extra field, you can pass an [optional argument](https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe/query-arguments.html#defining-arguments) in your query:

```ex
query do
  field :blog_posts, list_of(:blog_post) do
    arg :extra_data, :boolean
    resolve &MyAppWeb.Resolvers.Blog.posts/2
  end
end
```

---

### Multiple Extra Fields

But, if there are multiple optional arguments, it's better to use a custom [`input_object`](https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe/complex-arguments.html#content):

```ex
input_object :extra_input do
  field :extra_a, :boolean
  field :extra_b, :boolean
  field :extra_c, :boolean
end

query do
  field :blog_posts, list_of(:blog_post) do
    arg :extra_fields, :extra_input
    resolve &MyAppWeb.Resolvers.Blog.posts/2
  end
end
```

And in your resolver, you can get the request fields and build your HTTP request URL with them:

```ex
def posts(%{extra_fields: extra}, _resolution) do
  # Here `extra` is a map of the optional fields requested. You can
  # filter selected fields, map them to their HTTP service name and
  # construct the HTTP url and query params before calling it in
  # one go
end
```

---

<sup>*In both cases, remove the resolver you've specified directly on the `:extra_data` field in your `:blog_post` object.*</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I can fall back to a query argument, but I was hoping for a more idiomatic GraphQL solution i.e. mapping a part of the graph to the `extra-data` HTTP query parameter.

Comment: Since this isn't a common use-case, you won't find a solution that auto-magically™️ makes that transformation. Using query arguments is the correct approach here.

Comment: I think it's a common use case. I found two other GraphQL servers which do exactly this (let me examine selected nested fields in a higher-level resolver): https://lacinia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/selections.html#previewing-selections and https://sangria-graphql.org/learn/#projections . I guess I'll talk to the Absinthe folks about a feature request.

Comment: Found it! :-) Absinthe already has https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe/Absinthe.Resolution.html#project/2 which lets me check nested selections in the current query. I'll try this out and write up an answer.

Comment: Yes project is an alternative approach, but used to check if a certain field was requested in the graphql query. That would also solve your problem.

Comment: Let me know if you aren't able to do it yourself. I'll post another answer with the Project/Resolution approach.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't read the fine print before, `project` only gets the sub-fields _immediately below the current field_ in the resolver. Lacinia's `selects-field?` is more powerful, it can answer whether a field was used _anywhere_ in the query. I'm digging into the `Resolution` data structure now to try to do it manually.